# Jenkins and Github trigger PUSH from specific branch

Tags: git, jenkins, github

I set up the Github webhook in Jenkins and I created a job with the following configuration:

[image]

[image]

[image]

However, every time I push something from any branch, the job build a new version (using the branch which I specified).

I set up the job by reading some related questions on Stackoverflow but all those questions are quite old and without a clear solution:

[GitHub WebHooks triggered globally instead of per branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46140233/github-webhooks-triggered-globally-instead-of-per-branch)

[Trigger Jenkins job on GitHub PUSH to specific branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37099696/trigger-jenkins-job-on-github-push-to-specific-branch?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Is it possible to trigger Push only from a specific branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it by using **Multibranch Pipeline**.

- In Branch Sources:

  1. Add credentials and repository URL.
  2. In Behaviours add: Discover
     branches: all branches.
  3. Filter by name (with regular expression): for example, *^master|dev|release.*$*
- In Build Configuration add the path to the Jenkinsfile.

So the job will scan for all the branches of the repository that match with the regular expression.

Comment: It still doesn't solve the problem you mentioned in the question, just this config will trigger build for any commit to any branch.

Comment: your self answer does not make sense or does not solve your initial issue.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a GitHub Webhook to trigger a preconfigured job. Your Job has the Branch "JENKINS-TEST-AUTODEPLOYMENT" hardcoded, so it will always build this branch only, no matter which branch you are pushing on GitHub.

How about using [GitHub Branch Source Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/github-branch-source/)?
With this Plugin, Hooks will be auto-created in github for the corresponding repos. Each Branch will have a job in jenkins, which is also auto-created as long as you have a Jenkinsfile inside your Repo. With this your desired state should be easily achievable.

Comment: Thank you! I think this plugin works as well but finally I used Multibranch Pipeline.